# How to point to a task with it's own completions closure ? ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am sending request using tasks, in this way :

```
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    //remove from queue
                    weakself?.popTask(task: task)
    }
}

self.pushTask(task)
task.resume()
```

i need to push the task into a queue before resume. then i need to pop it after it's finished. the problem that i got this error : **variable used within it's own initial values**

what should i do?
is it possible to create a task, then to set it's completion handler ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're correct that the completion block can't refer to task because it hasn't been created yet.

That is what is meant by:

> variable used within it's own initial values

To get around this, simply declare the constant before you set it. e.g.

```
let task: NSURLSession
task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                //remove from queue
                weakself?.popTask(task: task)
}
```

Comment: does this create retain_cycle ?